# Solr MailEntityProcessor DIH configuration keeps loading

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih, requesthandler

I am trying to index my emails from Microsoft Exchange. The server is using IMAP4 protocols.
I added the requestHandler in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">---full path to data-config.xml---</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

And data-config.xml contains the following:

```
<dataConfig>
    <document>
        <entity processor="MailEntityProcessor"     
           user="username" 
           password="userpass" 
           host="host" 
           protocol="imaps"
           folders = "Inbox"
           processAttachement="false"/>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The problem is that when I go in Solr Admin UI-> select the core (collection1)->dataimport and when I click on the [+] sign that opens the configuration I get the "Loading ..." message and it keeps loading.

I have tried different options in data-config.xml (folders="inbox" and protocol="imap", protocol="pop", protocol="pop3", etc.) but nothing worked.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brnml.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this problem is fixed yet or not, but I stumbled upon the same problem and managed to find the problem.

The log files indicated that the entity in the data-config.xml file needed an entity name so you have to add the following to your entity:

**name="DataImport"** <-- this can be any name you like ofcourse.

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<document>
    <entity name="DataImport" 
       processor="MailEntityProcessor"     
       user="username" 
       password="userpass" 
       host="host" 
       protocol="imaps"
       folders = "Inbox"
       processAttachement="false"/>
</document>
```